# Logical equivalence of $x \in \{y\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it correct to state that $x \in \{y\}$ is logically equivalent to $x=y$, i.e. $\forall z[z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y]$? This idea seems a bit odd to me, because, if it is true, then $x \in \{y\} \leftrightarrow y \in \{x\}$ would be true as well.

Comment: What follows your "i.e." is nonsense because it is meaningless unless $x$ and $y$ are both sets, right?

Comment: Yes, this is true. However we cannot assume that $x$ nor $y$ is a set, so I would say that $z \in x$ is incorrect. I would say that $z=x$ instead

Comment: It seems that OP is working within the framework of ZF(C) set theory, where everything is considered to be a set, so that statement does have sense, I'd say.

Comment: Why would it be weird that $x\in\{y\}\leftrightarrow y\in\{x\}$ when $x=y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below a proof based on the definition of " uniqueness".

For a logical analysis of uniqueness and of definite descriptions, you may have a look at Bertrand Russell's paper " On denoting".

Also : https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell/#RWL

[image]

Comment: Is it correct to prove the contrapositive by just saying $x=y \rightarrow \{x\} \subseteq \{y\}$, since $x \in \{y\}$ is equivalent to $\{x\} \subseteq \{y\}$?

Comment: I think you mean " converse" statement.  The contrapositive of a conditional ( A ---> B) is not ( B ---> A) but rather ( ~B ---> ~A).  Your proof of the converse statement using inclusion of a singleton in the other seems fine to me,

Comment: Yes, I meant converse, not contrapositive. Thank you. As I can see, the proof of $x \in \{y\} \rightarrow x=y$ derives from the definition of uniqueness $\exists ! P(y) = \exists y[ P(y) \land \forall x [P(x) \rightarrow x=y]]$, where $P(y) = y \in \{y\}$, which is a tautology, and $P(x)=x \in \{y\}$. Thus, we have $\exists y \forall x [x \in \{y\} \rightarrow x=y]$.

Comment: Mr Littlerock, I was reviewing your answer and I stumbled upon a problem. You use the assumption $y \in \{y\} \land \forall z [z \in \{y\} \rightarrow z = y]$ to prove $x = y \leftrightarrow x \in \{y\}$. However, looking closely, I can't relate your assumption with the uniqueness definition, which requires an existential quantification, i. e. $\exists k[k \in \{y\} \land \forall z [z \in \{y\} \rightarrow z = k]]$. How did you existentially instantiated your assumption with the variable $y$ and used it to prove $x = y \leftrightarrow x \in \{y\}$?

Comment: I mean: that $y \in \{y\} \land \forall z [z \in \{y\} \rightarrow z = y]$ implies $x = y \leftrightarrow x \in \{y\}$ is totally clear for me. However, I cant' understand why $\exists k[k \in \{y\} \land \forall z [z \in \{y\} \rightarrow z = k]]$ implies $x = y \leftrightarrow x \in \{y\}$, since we are forced to instantiate $k$ with a variable that is not in the statement $x = y \leftrightarrow x \in \{y\}$.

Comment: In fact, I quantify existentially over variable y all over the proof from line 2 to the end. At line (2) I should have written more rigorously : there is some $y$ such that $y$ belongs to S and ...

Comment: So you made a good point

Answer (score 2):

When you write $x\in  \{y\}$, by definition, this means that $ x $ is an element of the set $ \{y\}$ which contains only one element. So, The unique element  of this set  is at the same time $ x $ and $ y $ . Thus $ x=y$.